# Spring AMQP: Comparing performance of multiple consumer vs multiple threads per consumer

Tags: java, performance, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp

Spring AMQP: Comparing performance of multiple consumer vs multiple threads per consumer

I'm in a phase of learning Spring AMQP from the Spring doc. I am not clear on preferred approach to increase consumption rate asynchronous message:
As per Spring documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e329) , following two points were noted for configuring a SimpleMessageListenerContainer:

1. concurrency => The number of concurrent consumers to start for each listener. On increasing the count, this would increase the number of consumers that would receive on the queue.
2. taskExecutor => This by default ensures new thread is created for each incoming message

So, I assume if we have unbounded threads for task execution (point 2) then there is no need to increase the number of consumers. Request to validate my assumption and send any performance points you have noted

Answer (score 4):

No; there is not a new thread for each incoming message; it has a thread per consumer. If you use a ThreadPool executor, it needs to have enough threads for the configured number of consumers. The default task executor is usually sufficient.

The consumer thread invokes your listener; if your listener takes, on average 1 second to process a message, then with a concurrency of 1, your max throughput is 1 per second; concurrency of 2, 2 per second. Etc, etc.